# File google-services.json is missing from module root folder

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

In my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // This is the last line
```

And I tried to put the `google-services.json` at:

```
+ build.gradle
+ app
  + google-services.json
+ src
  + app
    + google-services.json
  + main
    + app
      + google-service.json
```

But none of these json files was detect by the `google-services` plugin. It just keeps tell `File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.`

How should I config my gradle script? Where should I put the json file?

Comment: It should be in app folder > **ProjectName\app\google-services.json**

Comment: @Gaurav So you mean the `app` folder should be the same place as the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Yes ProjectLevel build.gradle, You will find one more build.gradle (module level ) in app folder

Comment: From project view it should be parallel to manifest file

Comment: Dont look at **ProjectExplorer**  go to the path of your project

Comment: @VivekMishra I tried all the places. Could that because there are something not right in my `gradle` script?

Comment: you haven't added play services in your gradle file and more over current version for google services is `8.4` and you are using 2.0

Comment: Now JSON file is available at: **\sdk\platforms\android-N\optional\optional.json**

Comment: @VivekMishra The 2.0 is the version of the plugin

Comment: what google service you are using?

Answer (score 0):

google-services.json need to add in app folder.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question. I tried 3 different place to put the app folder, so does the json file within it, but the plug still tell not found.

Comment: Then please recreate you google-services.json file it may mismatched you project identities.